# Enclosing brackets when setting variables

Tags: linux, unix

Why does this command destroy the search path?

```
PATH=($PATH:$HOME/bin)
```

The PATH appears unchanged, but the shell cannot find commands.

It was entered in error for

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Probably confused with

```
PATH=$(echo $PATH:$HOME/bin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using parentheses you create an array:

```
$ a=(x:y:z v:w:x)
$ echo ${a[0]}
x:y:z
$ echo ${a[1]}
v:w:x
```

In your case you created an array with one element (the whole path).  This is then not interpreted anymore as the path to search for executables.  This `PATH` has to be a string of directories separated by colons, not an array.

Comment: More details can be found here - once you know what is the problem. :-) [link]http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-using-arrays.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to acheive PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

Try `PATH=(\$PATH:\$HOME/bin)`